# R Shiny call tables in dynamic tabs

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have data tables in dynamic tabs, which will require the user to input data. How to call those tables and process the user data from the dynamic tabs?

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

DF <- data.frame(sample=c(350292, 350293), test=c(2, 3))

runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('Dynamic Tabs'),
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("nTabs", 'No. of Tabs', 5)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput('mytabs')  
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    output$mytabs = renderUI({
      nTabs = input$nTabs
      myTabs = lapply(paste('Tab', 1: nTabs), tabPanel,
                  rhandsontable(DF))
      do.call(tabsetPanel, myTabs)
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Not clear what you really wanted

Comment: I modified the description. Essentially because the tabs are dynamically created. I failed to call them or call the tables in these tabs.

Comment: Is the source of your problem that the tables aren't available because they haven't been rendered yet?  If that's the case, see `outputOptions`

Comment: I guess so, because the tables/tabs are dynamically created. Could you explain more how to utilized outputOptions. Thanks.